# Responding to Touch using Crafty

Tags: javascript, cordova, craftyjs

I'm trying to create a game using Crafty JS, that I eventually want to deploy via PhoneGap.  Out of the box, the `.fourway()` method doesn't respond to touch on my Android device.  Is there in-built support for touch?  Is there a component I can use to add touch capabilities, or do I have to set this up manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Touch events in Crafty are [normalised as Mouse events](http://craftyjs.com/api/Crafty-touchDispatch.html). `fourway` is specifically [tied to keyboard events](http://craftyjs.com/api/Fourway.html).

You might have some joy using the [moveTo component](http://craftycomponents.com/components/single/15/moveto) instead of `fourway`